# Caching and bindModel in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, caching

I use plugin [Comments from CakeDC](http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_comments_plugin)  and have big problem in production mode (debug=0). If I understand correctly, CakePHP cache models at first request and CakePHP using this cache unless expires. This plugin connects additional model to existing models using bindModel(). But since all models is caching, connecting additional model is not happen, and everything crashing.

How to use the cache in situations where there is use bindModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you only need to make sure your plugin is defined in your bootstrap right away:

```
 CakePlugin::load('Comments');
```

this way you can use it anywhere later on.
and the cache won't cause any problems

Comment: you didnt mention your cake version (so one assumes the current) - please do that the next time you ask for help here. in 1.3 all plugins are available by default. so there shouldnt be any issues here regarding the cache. maybe the problem is somewhere else?